# What is the story of Sītā (wife of Rāma) killing Śatānana Rākṣasa?

Tags: rama, hanuman, reference-request, sita

Sītā with the help of Hanumān killed a Rākṣasa called Śatānana (hundred headed). What is the story of it and which scripture includes it?

Comment: Perhaps this question is a duplicate of [this one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14717/sahasra-mukhi-thousand-faced-raavana-killed-by-sita)?

Comment: @KVickneshvara No, not at all because that question was answered by me.

Comment: @student assuming that you are a telugu speaker, I would like to see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiHEovHrtYo) video.